# Which would be the best UX?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, mobile-development

Actually, I'm a beginner to the development.I want to know one thing.

I have a form in my app which contain few fields to make the user fill their details(not long details).if the user navigate to another page and coming back to that ,the filled data should persist or not ? which would be considered as best UX ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understood your problem states is that you have a form with a few fields. Let's call this form `formA`. If I - a user - enter a few details into these fields, and then I navigate away from `formA` to any other page. Then I decide that I clicked something wrong and need to go back. When I go back, should I be presented with whatever I entered, or with a blank form as if I never came there.

It is a golden rule of UI/UX design to [permit reversal of actions easily](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/shneiderman-s-eight-golden-rules-will-help-you-design-better-interfaces#6._permit_reversal_of_actions-7:%7E:text=away%20most%20users!-,6.%20Permit%20reversal%20of%20actions,-When%20users%20make). If I want to start over, I can erase the details and start over. If, however, I wanted to resume but couldn't, that'd be annoying. If I were designing the form, I'd save progress.

Comment: Yeah , Understood your point. Thanks for your answer.